# How to read multiple files from the same directory using File::Tail?

Tags: perl

I am writing a program to read the rules and logs file from a IDS system.
I am using File::Tail function inside Perl
Cannot figure out how to use it.
Here are some of my examples...

Example 1

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Fail::tail;

opendir RUL, "/etc/snort/rules" || die "Could not open RUL directory\n $!";

my @allrule = grep {/.rules$/} readdir RUL;
close RUL;

   foreach my $rulefile (@allrule)
   {
      open(LF, "/etc/snort/rules/$rulefile") or die "$！";
      while(<LF>)

       print "$\n";
   }
```

with this example I am able to print all the rules on my terminal...
How to change the rules using file::tail function and even write all the rules to a new file?

I tried this:

```
Example 2
#!/user/local/bin/perl
.
.
.
foreach my $rulefile(@allfule)
{
   $file = File::Tail->new("/etc/snort/rules/$rulefile");
   while (defined(my $line = $file -> read))
   {
       print $line;
   }
}
```

Example 2 would not run.
Anyone have any ideas as to why it does not run ?

Comment: what do you mean by "would not run"? Exactly how does it fail? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: get nothing...like the program is running but nth print out and no exit...

Comment: At what point do you think ->read will return undef?

Answer (score 4):

I have not worked with File::Tail, but based on its CPAN documentation and the behavior you are seeing it looks like once you start it tailing that first file in your array, it stays there waiting until you stop tailing that file.

Have a look at the [usage of select with File::Tail from CPAN](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aTail#select).

It looks like you basically need to use File::Tail::select and pass an array of File::Tail objects to it along with whatever other basic logic you need, of course, such as the loop shown in the example, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Writing it to a file:

```
open(my $outfile, ">/path/to/someoutfile") or die $!; # use >> if you want to append instead of overwrite
foreach my $rulefile(@allfule)
{
   $file = File::Tail->new("/etc/snort/rules/$rulefile");
   while (defined(my $line = $file->read))
   {
       print $outfile $line;
   }
}
close($outfile);
```

Hopefully helps you with your immediate problem. I have a feeling there's a better way to do it but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish. For the logs `Fail::Tail` makes sense, but (i'm assuming) the rule files are static so `Fail::Tail` seems unnecessary.

Comment: thank for your comment...I am using Fail::tail for rule files because the rule file will update after sometime..other then that any better idea to update the rule file?...my idea is like that at 1st will copy all the rule file to a same file..and my program will read the log file and those packet which match the rule file will alert admin or user. so the program only access one file to match the packet which is faster access all folder again...once there is some update of the rule file will auto update the combine rule file...

Comment: if i want to apply Fail::Tail:Select function how should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you mean File::Tail? (I can't find a Fail::Tail on CPAN).

The documentation at [File::Tail](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aTail) says:

> read
>
> read returns one line from the input
>   file. If there are no lines ready, it
>   blocks until there are.

So your loop will never reliably complete. I have never looked at File::Tail before, but I *think* you need to take note of where it says

> nowait
>
> Does not block on read, but returns an empty string if there is
>   nothing to read. DO NOT USE THIS
>   unless you know what you are doing. If
>   you are using it in a loop, you
>   probably DON'T know what you are
>   doing. If you want to read tails from
>   multiple files, use select.

Comment: sorry i face a problem...I am using fedora 14..and after i finish configure snort and run it, it's seem that the max size of log file is 128 MB. There are two questions: 1) how the File::Tail function know which file should be the latest file? 2)can File::Tail switch to the new file while the old one is full?