# How do I fix high MultiTail CPU consumption in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have written a script with Perl that basically multitails files (using the Perl library [File::MultiTail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MultiTail)): after tailing each lines it does many other things but that's another story, so I just paste a resume based on the piece of code that's causing problems:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use File::MultiTail;

$path="my/path";
$files="*.log";

sub first{
    $True=0;
    my $file=MultiTail->new(OutputPrefix => 'f',
    Files => ["$path"],
    RemoveDuplicate => $True,
    ScanForFiles => "0");

    while(defined(my $line=$file->read)) {
        print"$line\n";
        $file->update_attribute(Files => ["$path"]);
    }

}

&first();
```

The script works well: it tails every single line from several files each time a new log line arise, but my problem is that this script uses 100% CPU, and I was wondering how I could make it not be checking the files at every single second, I can do so with a delay like sleep 10; and it really liberates the CPU, but I need to see the lines in real time and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: _after tailing it does many other things_: are you sure this subroutine is taking all CPU time? Have you already done profiling with [NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) or some other profiling tool?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `File::MultiTail` is an old piece of code ( 1998 ): maybe it isn't doing file checks in an efficient way, or it doesn't scale well with growing number of files. 
Doing as many I/O checks as possible in that while loop, looks as a waste of CPU time.

Maybe you can spare CPU cycles on I/O using a more recent module like [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm), because *The module tries very hard NOT to "busy-wait"*.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use File::Tail;

my @logs  = glob '/var/log/*.log';
my @tails = ();

foreach ( @logs ) {
    push @tails, File::Tail->new( $_ );
}

foreach ( @tails ) {
    while ( defined ( my $line = $_->read ) ) {
        say $line;
    }
}
```

In order to know if this more CPU friendly than `File::MultiTail`, you have to check CPU time ( real, user, sys ).

Answer (score 1):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380640/how-to-read-multiple-files-from-the-same-directory-using-filetail/5380790#5380790) is what you are looking for. See [usage of select with File::Tail from CPAN](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aTail#select).